# Is a directory (os error 21) when using rust to move a file

Tags: rust

I want to use rust to move a file(or folder) from folder A to another folder, this is my code look like:

```
use std::{fs, path::PathBuf};

fn main() {
    let mut file_path = PathBuf::from("/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/apps/a");
    let mut destination_path = PathBuf::from("/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/apps/test/");
    let result = fs::rename(file_path, destination_path);
    if let Err(err) = result {
        print!("{}",err);
    }
}
```

`a` is a plain text file. when I run this code in Linux(CentOS 7.8)/macOS(13.3.1 (a) ), shows error:

```
Is a directory (os error 21)%
```

Am I missing something? I have read the docs and example from web, it seems could not work like this. what should I do to fixed this issue? This is the rust version info:

```
> rustup -V
rustup 1.27.0 (bbb9276d2 2024-03-08)
info: This is the version for the rustup toolchain manager, not the rustc compiler.
info: The currently active `rustc` version is `rustc 1.77.1 (7cf61ebde 2024-03-27)`
```

Comment: destination should not be a directory but a file name. `".../apps/test/a"`. I guess you were expecting this to work because the `mv` unix command automatically appends the file name to the directory if it is missing, but the `rename()` system-call does not. In `man 2 rename`: « EISDIR newpath is an existing directory, but oldpath is  not  a  directory.»

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the code snippet, you provide, `file_path` is a file while `destination_path` is a directory. This is not permitted in rust on linux. According to the [docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/fn.rename.html#platform-specific-behavior):

> On Unix, if `from` is a directory, `to` must also be an (empty) directory. If `from` is not a directory, `to` must also be not a directory.

Instead you can do this:

```rust
use std::{fs, path::PathBuf};

fn main() {
    let file_path = PathBuf::from("/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/apps/a");
    let destination_path = PathBuf::from("/Users/xiaoqiangjiang/apps/test/a"); // added file name at the end
    let result = fs::rename(file_path, destination_path);
    if let Err(err) = result {
        println!("{}", err);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The relevant part of [the documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/fn.rename.html) is this:

> On Unix, if […] `from` is not a directory, `to` must also be not a directory. In contrast, on Windows, `from` can be anything, but `to` must not be a directory.

I.e. `to` *may not be* a directory, but you've passed the name of a directory to the second parameter.

So you'll have to append the file name to the directory name yourself:

```rust
let file_path = PathBuf::from("apps/a");
let mut destination_path = PathBuf::from("apps/test/");

destination_path.push(file_path.file_name().unwrap());

let result = fs::rename(file_path, destination_path).unwrap();
```